# Send user inputs from view to component in Angular 15

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new in Angular, and I'm currently working on an Angular 15 project, so I have a `.ts` component where I get some info from an API:

```
export class CustomPersonalSettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  

    constructor(
        private personalSettingsService: PersonalSettingService,
        private config: ConfigStateService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
      ){}
    
      ngOnInit() { 
        const currentUserId = this.config.getOne("currentUser").id;
    
        this.personalSettingsService.get(currentUserId).subscribe((settings) => {
          this.personalSettings = settings;
            })
      } 
    }
```

This is getting my entity on `this.personalSettings` object which is the following

```
export interface PersonalSettingDto extends EntityDto<string> {
  userName?: string;
  email?: string;
  name?: string;
  surname?: string;
  phoneNumber?: string;
  selectedTimeZone?: string;
  timeZoneList: TimeZoneDto[];
}
```

Now I want to populate the inputs with the received data on my HTML, so I created HTML view as:

```
<div class="mb-3 ng-star-inserted">
  <label for="username" class="form-label ng-star-inserted">User name</label>
  <input ng-model="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" id="username" autocomplete="off"
    type="text">
</div>
<div class="w-50 d-inline">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="name" name="name">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="w-50 d-inline">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label" for="surname">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="surname" name="surname">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mb-3 d-inline-block w-50 ps-4 ng-star-inserted"></div>

<div class="mb-3 ng-star-inserted">
  <label for="email-address" class="form-label ng-star-inserted">Email address* </label>
  <input class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" id="email-address" autocomplete="off"
    type="text">
</div>

<div class="mb-3 ng-star-inserted"><label for="phone-number" class="form-label ng-star-inserted">Phone number</label>
  <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" id="phone-number" autocomplete="off"
    type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="priority">Time Zone</label>
  <select class="form-control">
    <option [ngValue]="null">Select your time zone</option>
    <option *ngFor="let timeZone of personalSettings.timeZoneList" [ngValue]="timeZone.id">
      {{ timeZone.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="send()">
  <i class="fa fa-check mr-1"></i>
  Send
</button>
```

As you can see, it has a button that executes send function inside the `ts` file:

```
  send(){ }
```

But how can I send the data to that method?
To achieve this, two tasks (Populate inputs with current data onInit function and send data to API):
I read that you need to wrap everything in a form to achieve that, but I need help understanding how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `personalSettings` model to the form inputs. Hence you first need to declare an instance of type `PersonalSettingDto` inside your Component. I assume `personalSettings` is a single object and not an array of objects as its name indicates.

```html
export class CustomPersonalSettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  
    personalSettings: PersonalSettingDto = {} as PersonalSettingDto;

    constructor(
        private personalSettingsService: PersonalSettingService,
        private config: ConfigStateService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
      ){}
    
      ngOnInit() { 
        const currentUserId = this.config.getOne("currentUser").id;
    
        this.personalSettingsService.get(currentUserId).subscribe((settings) => {
          this.personalSettings = settings;
            })
      } 
    }
```

Then you need to bind the model using `ngModel` directives to your html page as below, so that the model is synced with user inputs.

```html
<div class="mb-3 ng-star-inserted">
  <label for="username" class="form-label ng-star-inserted">User name</label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="personalSettings.userName" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" id="username" autocomplete="off"     type="text">
</div>
<div class="w-50 d-inline">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <input  [(ngModel)]="personalSettings.name" type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="name" name="name">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="w-50 d-inline">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label" for="surname">Surname</label>
    <input  [(ngModel)]="personalSettings.surname" type="text" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="surname" name="surname">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mb-3 d-inline-block w-50 ps-4 ng-star-inserted"></div>

<div class="mb-3 ng-star-inserted">
  <label for="email-address" class="form-label ng-star-inserted">Email address* </label>
  <input  [(ngModel)]="personalSettings.email" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" id="email-address" autocomplete="off" type="text">
</div>

<div class="mb-3 ng-star-inserted"><label for="phone-number" class="form-label ng-star-inserted">Phone number</label>
  <input  [(ngModel)]="personalSettings.phoneNumber" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" id="phone-number" autocomplete="off"
    type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="priority">Time Zone</label>
  <select  [(ngModel)]="personalSettings.selectedTimeZone" class="form-control">
    <option [ngValue]="null">Select your time zone</option>
    <option *ngFor="let timeZone of personalSettings.timeZoneList" [ngValue]="timeZone.id">
      {{ timeZone.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="send()">
  <i class="fa fa-check mr-1"></i>
  Send
</button>
```

Now the form inputs will be bound into the `personalSettings` model and available inside `send()` function for further validation or transactional processing.